# JavaFX: Rotate Transformation with Shapes don´t work with a fixed point

Tags: javafx, draggable, rotatetransform

I try to make a rectangle changeable with the mouse. The upper left corner should be fix. Without any rotation of the rectangle it works. But if the rectangle is rotated, it does´t work anymore.

All attemps with sceneToLocal and vice versa and with "rectangle.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(-ang, w, h));" doesn´t  work. The fixPoint is not fix, if the angle<>0!

Does somebody has any idea?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RotatedRectangle extends Application {

    private final int TSIZE = 12;
    Rectangle rec,fixPoint;
double angle =0;// 0 works fine, but for other angle the fixPoint is not fix!

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Group recGroup = new Group();
    recGroup.setRotate(angle);
    rec = new Rectangle(100,100,300, 200);
    rec.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    rec.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    fixPoint = new Rectangle(10,10);
    fixPoint.xProperty().bind(rec.xProperty());
    fixPoint.yProperty().bind(rec.yProperty());
    Rectangle recSE = TouchRectangle(
            rec.xProperty().add(rec.widthProperty()).subtract(TSIZE),
            rec.yProperty().add(rec.heightProperty()).subtract(TSIZE));

    recGroup.getChildren().addAll(rec, recSE,fixPoint);
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.getChildren().add(recGroup);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Rotated Rectangle");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


private Rectangle TouchRectangle(ObservableValue<? extends Number> x, ObservableValue<? extends Number> y) {
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    r.setHeight(TSIZE);
    r.setWidth(TSIZE);
    r.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    r.setStroke(Color.RED);
    r.xProperty().bind(x);
    r.yProperty().bind(y);        
    r.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            Point2D zero = rec.localToScene(rec.getX() + rec.getWidth(),
                    rec.getY() + rec.getHeight());                
            double newX = (event.getSceneX() - zero.getX());
            double newY = (event.getSceneY() - zero.getY());
            rec.setWidth(rec.getWidth() +newX);
            rec.setHeight(rec.getHeight() +newY);
            Point2D fixP = fixPoint.localToScene(fixPoint.getX(), fixPoint.getY());
            System.out.println("FIX??"+fixP);
        }
    });
    return r;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply set the `rotate` property of a node, it will rotate that node *around its center point*. If you subsequently change the dimensions, the center will move, so you will see the opposite end of the rectangle move as well.

To keep that point fixed, perform the rotation around that point. So instead of

```
recGroup.setRotate(angle);
```

do

```
Rotate rotate = new Rotate(angle, 0, 0);
recGroup.getTransforms().add(rotate);
```

You will likely need to add some translation, or just move the original rectangle, but this will keep the (0,0) point of the rectangle fixed.

Comment: So far I have always believed that these functions are equal.

Comment: recGroup.setRotate(angle) <==>Rotate rotate = new Rotate(angle, rec.getX()+rec.getWidth()/2.,rec.getY()+rec.getHeight()/2.);
        recGroup.getTransforms().add(rotate); These example shows the difference. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, those are not quite identical, because the `Rotate` created by `setRotate` updates its pivot point if the bounds change. So you'd really need `Rotate rotate = new Rotate(angle);` `rotate.pivotXProperty().bind(rec.xProperty().add(rec.widthProperty().divide(2)));` etc. But, yes, that's the idea.